# Preg_match find numbers in string after Dash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters

Good Morning,

I have an error in my preg_match. My string is `Cat-115/Ads-733-49` and i want find last numbers after dash `Cat-115/Ads-733-` and print that

Could you please help me fix this? I am sure, it some basic error, so sorry for that...

My Code :

```
 $destination = "Cat-115/Ads-733-49";
 preg_match('/Ads-\K\d+/', $destination,$m);
 $result=  $m[0];
```

i need to result in this case is `49` 
Thanks!

Comment: `'/\d+$/'` will do the job here. If you need to make sure there is a `-`, modify your pattern to `'/-\K\d+$/'`. BTW, you say you have an error in `preg_replace`, but you have `preg_match` in your code. See [**this PHP demo**](https://ideone.com/jSGsbP).

Comment: preg_match('/Ads-/\d+$/', $destination,$m); ?????

Comment: See https://ideone.com/jSGsbP

Comment: thanks man work like charm :d